# How to arrange data in the source order after using csv.DictReader()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a csv file into a dictionary for calculation purposes and print it in exactly the same order (e.g. a, b, c, d, etc.) as they were in the original csv file.

I just learnt and tried using **csv.DictReader(file)** but I realized every time I did a print, the sequence of the row, column keeps changing, or I would say it mess up randomly.

Any solution for this or is there any part I did wrong?

```
import csv

with open("breast_cancer_v1.csv", 'r') as file:
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in csv_file:
        print(dict(row))
```

I had name my column header as "a, b, c ,d ,e ,f ,h, i, j, k, l, m" inside my csv but the print sequence mess up as below:

output

[image]

notice the dictionary keys are not in order and my rows are also facing the same problem if i have too many rows in the csv (e.g. 100+ rows)

My original csv data looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you really want to print it as a dictionary, then you have to give each column a name with the fieldnames option:

```
    import csv

    with open("artist.csv", newline='') as file:
      fieldnames = ['first_col', 'sec_col',...,'last_col']
      csv_file = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        for row in csv_file:
           print(row)
```

The order you list the fieldnames in will be the order they appear in. You'll have to remove the original column header in your csv file.

Comment: Thanks. but can i know what is the purpose of indicating fieldnames? because if i just type 

"csv_file = cs.DicReader(file)"

The same result appears except on the first line print out it will not show the column header.

Comment: Oh, i think i know what it does, the fieldnames helps to "re label" the keys assigned to values on that column. if i am right,

Comment: Do you want the print out to be an actual dictionary?      like so, for each line{'A': 456, 'B': 5678, 'C': 'ssfs',....}

Comment: Actually, i am trying to copy select rows in the CSV to another new CSV file. Thought of rename the header with numbers and easier to call them out for further manipulating.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print in order just use this:

```
   import csv

   with open("breast_cancer_v1.csv", 'r') as file:
       for row in file:
           print(row)
```